Label smoothing without having to one-hot encode
I want to use label smoothing regularization for my NMT task. As suggested the way it is done is as follows
loss_object = CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, reduction='none')

def masked_loss_function(y_true, pred, smoothing_factor=0.1):
    mask = tf.logical_not(tf.equal(y_true, fa_tokenizer.pad_token_id))
    y_hot = (1 - smoothing_factor) * tf.one_hot(y_true, depth=VOCAB_TARG_SIZE) + (smoothing_factor / VOCAB_TARG_SIZE)
    loss = loss_object(y_hot, pred)
    mask = tf.cast(mask, loss.dtype)
    loss *= mask
    return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)

the problem is that I am using RTX 2060 notebook with 6GB of ram and one_hot encoding a vector that explodes to a shape like [64, 30, 25000] is expensive (I am using float32).
I was looking for an alternative way to carry these computations sparsely. Can anybody help me?
I tried choosing y_pred from y_true to carry
chosen = choose positive indices from y_pred
$
-\sum_i (1-smoothing_factor) \times log(chosen) + (\frac{smoothing_factor}{num_classes} log(all))
$

I'm surprised that one_hot doesn't have an option to output a sparse tensor; do downstream operations just not generally work with sparse tensors??  Maybe a feature request is in order?

I was just wondering if we could incorporate temperature into the loss function. I don't know how legitimate this is.
